# How to remove these message from intelliJ when I enter a new Terminal window?

Tags: terminal

It seems since I installed IDEA, every time I enter a new Terminal window, it will print these message:

```
/Users/~ /Users/~/.jetbrains.vmoptions.sh
/Users/~ /Users/~/.jetbrains.vmoptions.sh
```

Comment: DId you check the init files of your shell?

Comment: Yes, I do. I thought of this and solved it just after I post this question. Thank you for answering. @nohillside

Comment: Please post the steps you took as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Finaly I checked `.bash_profile` `.zshrc` and then commend out these lines:

```
___MY_VMOPTIONS_SHELL_FILE="${HOME}/.jetbrains.vmoptions.sh"; if [ -f 
"${___MY_VMOPTIONS_SHELL_FILE}" ]; then . "${___MY_VMOPTIONS_SHELL_FILE}"; fi
```

I don't know what's the use of this code, but at least I got some peace of mind. Maybe there is a more elegant way yet. @nohillside